# Lazy deletion on hash tables

Tags: data-structures, hashtable

In my implementation I use lazy deletion with linear or quadratic probing for collision resolution.  For insertions, when I encounter a lazily deleted item, I replace it with the item to be inserted.  What are the disadvantages or incorrectness of doing it this way(for either linear or quadratic or double hash collision resolution)?  Doesn't it save space?

Comment: I won't add an answer since this is extremely open-ended, but two other things you should be aware of is that different hashing schemes require different classes of hash function to achieve their runtime complexity bounds (google "universal hash function"), and that the different hashing schemes may perform very differently on a real machine than you expect because of reference locality - accessing values further away in from each other in memory space may cause cache misses and make the otherwise more performant scheme less performant!

Answer (score 2):

The problem with open addressed hashtables is that their performance degrades over time, especially when the entries are very dynamic.

For example lets consider a simple linear probed list. If you had 3 collisions on hash slot 1, slots 1, 2, 3 will be used. If 2 gets deleted you need to mark it as "was used before" to still be able to find the item in slot 3. With certain usage patterns this will degrade your hashtable to a point where the linear search time increases more and more, requiring a costly rehash to make it effective again.

Close addressed hashtables will be more constant in their performance over time, when inserting/deleting lots of items. But they are not as cache-friendly because you'll have to fiddle around with pointers.

So, if you have nearly constant keys, go with open addressing, otherwise consider close addressed hashtables.

For certain problems you might also want to look into other concepts like cuckoo hashing.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do lazy deletion from a linear probed open addressed hash table. Hard deletion can be done simply in constant time with no table degredation. There was pseudo code for it on the Wikipedia Hash Table page for years. I don't know why is isn't there any more, but here is a permalink back to when it was: [Old Wikipedia Hash Table page](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Hash_table&oldid=95275577), and here for your convenience is the pseudocode:

```
function remove(key)
 i := find_slot(key)
 if slot[i] is unoccupied
     return   // key is not in the table
 j := i
 loop
     j := (j+1) modulo num_slots
     if slot[j] is unoccupied
         exit loop
     k := hash(slot[j].key) modulo num_slots
     if (j > i and (k <= i or k > j)) or
        (j < i and (k <= i and k > j)) (note 2)
         slot[i] := slot[j]
         i := j
 mark slot[i] as unoccupied
```

There is also a ref on that page to some [real code](http://ici.cvs.sourceforge.net/ici/ici/set.c?view=markup). I believe this has exactly the same performance characteristic as insertion and restores the table to as good a state as if the entry was never added.

This method of deletion is better than the much used 'mark deleted and occasionally rehash everything' because the above method is constant time rather than amortized constant time. If you have a hash table of a million items you are adding and deleting from, in the 'mark deleted' method, an occasional add or delete is going to take a million times longer than the ones before and after it - which is not a good performance characteristic.

Comment: It's a more recent result than this answer, but properly designed lazy deletion ameliorates primary clustering degradation to some extent.   It is now known to be a good idea to implement it in most linear probed hashtables.  (See Bender, Kuszmaul, and Kuszmaul 2021, eg)